# What does "*" do to the properties?

Tags: css, properties

I was taking a look in the bootstrap css files. And I notice that some properties were duplicated but, with "*" before them. Example:

`width: 65.95744680851064%; *width: 65.90425531914893%;`

What does that mean?

Comment: okay, i didn't find anything so i asked a new one. thank you

Answer (score 3):

It is a syntax error. Some browsers have bugs in css parsing, so one can exploit the bug so some rules apply only to certain browsers